# How can I find contiguous sequences of duplicate elements in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I need to write a function that given a list of integers `L` and integer `n`, it returns `True` if the list contains a consecutive sequence of ones of length `n`, and `False` otherwhise.

Let's say my list is : `L = [1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4]` and `n` = 3.
The function should return `True` because there are 3 ones at the 5th position.

I tried with:

```
def consecutive (L,n):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if [1]*n in L:
            return True
    return False
L = [1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4]
n = 3
consecutive (L,n)
```

But this is not working of course, because `[1]*3` generate `[1,1,1]` and there are not sublist inside `L`.

Is there any way using list comprehension? Something like:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4]
result = all(x==(1,1,1) for x in range(0,len(L)+1,3))
result
```

Again, I know is not working because each element `x` can't be equal to `(1,1,1)`. I wrote it down just to give an idea of what was in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using imports

**Ex:**

```
L = [1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4]
n = 3
def consecutive (L,n):
    c = 0
    for i in L:
        if i == 1:
            c += 1
        else:
            c = 0
        if c >= n:
            return True
    return False


print(consecutive(L,n))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which allows you to group consecutive values in the list. The following generator comprehension returns `True` if a given `key` of `1` is found, and the length of its corresponding values is `>=` than `n`.

We can use `next` to stop iterating as soon as the first `True` is returned:

```
from itertools import groupby
n = 3

next((True for k,v in groupby(L) if k == 1 and len(list(v)) >= n), False)
# True
```

Comment: Let's suppose I can't use any Python's module. Any hint?

Comment: What is the problem with importing a module? You 're going to have to get conformable with imports if using python...

Comment: You are perfectly right! But that's a tricky point of my homework requirements: it is not allowed to import modules.

Comment: Well I will leave this answer anyway for future visitors, and as it was not explicitly stated in the question that no modules should be imported

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import modules (which I am guessing this is homework) then you can do something like this:

```
n = 3
L = [1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,3,4]
find = [1] * n

locations = [index for index in range(len(L)) if index <= len(L) and L[index: index + len(find)] == find]

for location in locations:
    print(f"Found {find} at index {location}.")
```

**Output:**

```
Found [1, 1, 1] at index 4.
```

Though you may want to consider doing this the long way instead of list comprehension to learn the language.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if want to know if ***any*** list element is repeated. The following returns `True` if and only if there is a sequence of `n` copies of any element:

```
def consecutive (L,n):
    if len(L) < 1:
        return False
    if n <= 1:
        return True

    # at this point n >= 2
    elem = L[0]
    count = 1
    # so far, we have seen one copy of `elem`

    for i in range(1, len(L)):
        if L[i] == elem:
            count = count + 1
            if count >= n:
                return True
        else: # L[i] != elem
            elem = L[i]
            count = 1
    return False
```

If there is a ***specific*** element you care about repeating, then consider the following:

```
def consecutive (L,n, elem):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if L[i] == elem:
            count = count + 1
            if count >= n:
                return True
        else: # L[i] != elem
            count = 0
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

As @yatu stated, using `itertools` is obviously the best way to do it.

But this can be reproduced by zipping slices of the original list. In example, to group items of list by 3, you could do:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]

def groupby3(a_list):
    return zip(a_list[:-2], a_list[1:-1], a_list[2:])

print([l for l in groupby3(l)])
# [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1), (4, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Grouping items by any number is a bit more complex since we have to build the slice dynamically:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]

def groupbyn(a_list, n):
    # computes the bounds of slices to use
    bounds = ((start or None, start - n + 1 or None) for start in range(n))
    # builds a slice for each generated bounds couple
    slices = (slice(start, stop) for start, stop in bounds)
    # apply the generated slices
    sliced = (a_list[slice] for slice in slices)
    # return the sipped slices
    return zip(*sliced)

print([l for l in groupbyn(l, 3)])
# [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1), (4, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
print([l for l in groupbyn(l, 2)])
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
print([l for l in groupbyn(l, 5)])
# [(1, 2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 3, 4, 1, 1), (3, 4, 1, 1, 1), (4, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Then you can use this `groupbyn` function to address your problem:

```py
n = 3
print((1, ) * n in groupbyn(l, n))  # True
n = 4
print((1, ) * n in groupbyn(l, n))  # False
```